# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'pop' - Python list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have

```py
    my_dict = {
          "test_environments": [
            {
              "Branch Coverage": "97/97(100%)",
              "project" : 'ok'
            },
            {
              "Branch Coverage": "36/36(100%)",
              "project" :'ok'
            }
          ]
        }
```

How could I delete the key Branch Coverage? I'm trying with this code:

```
   for index, _ in enumerate(my_dict['test_environments']):
        for key, values in my_dict['test_environments'][index].items():
            key.pop("Branch Coverage")
```

Comment: `test_environments` have an invalid syntax. some curly braces are not closed, and no comma separating them. Please edit your question and post the code you are actually running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `del` keyword to remove keys from a dictionary in-place.

```py
my_dict = {
          "test_environments": [
                {
                  "Branch Coverage": "97/97(100%)",
                  "project" : 'ok'
                },
                {
                  "Branch Coverage": "36/36(100%)",
                  "project" :'ok'
                }
        ]
    }

for element in my_dict["test_environments"]:
    del element["Branch Coverage"]

# Prints {'test_environments': [{'project': 'ok'}, {'project': 'ok'}]}
print(my_dict)
```

Comment: You can still use `pop`; you  just have to call it on the correct object (the dict, not the key).

Answer (score 0):

You call `pop` on the `dict` object you want to modify, not the key you want to remove.

```
for d in my_dict['test_environments']:
    d.pop("Branch Coverage")
```